# I am getting an error while running my angular6 application locally

Tags: angular, html

I am trying to run my angular6 application locally and I am getting an error like this

core.js:1624 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL  cannot be created in a document with origin localhost. Attaching the screenshot of my browser console.

Thanks in Advance[image]

Comment: it states that these are two different states for two applications and seems that local app is trying to save some other origin of application.

Comment: @Jai didnt get your point... Can you please make it little more clear? If you could explain it in detail it would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: have you created route file or it is new fresh project?

Comment: it is a new fresh project. I have a route file which contains the routes info for all the routes.